# How to unpivot columns in kusto/kql/azure and put multiple columns into one

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-java-sdk

I got a table like this in Azure analytics with Kusto for the game I'm working on

```
datatable (ID_player:string, Timestamp:timespan, monster1:int, monster2:int, monster3:int)
[
     "aaa", "12:00:00", 1,2,3
    ,"aaa", "12:10:00", 4,7,0
    ,"bbb", "12:30:00", 0,2,1
]
```

Basically, I need to switch to a format like this one

```
ID_Player     Timespamp     Monster     Quantity
aaa           12:00:00      Monster1      1
aaa           12:00:00      Monster2      2
aaa           12:00:00      Monster3     3
aaa           12:10:00      Monster1     4
aaa           12:10:00      Monster2      7
aaa           12:10:00      Monster3      0
bbb           12:30:00      Monster1      0
bbb           12:30:00      monster2      2
bbb           12:30:00      Monster3      1
```

ny idea? I tought to use a series of CASE WHEN But I don't think it's the right solution.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 3 more straightforward solutions, based on [mv-expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator) & [pack_dictionary()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packdictionaryfunction) / [pack_array()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packarrayfunction)

###### `pack_dictionary()` + `mv-expand kind = array`

```
datatable (ID_player:string, Timestamp:timespan, monster1:int, monster2:int, monster3:int)
[
     "aaa", "12:00:00", 1,2,3
    ,"aaa", "12:10:00", 4,7,0
    ,"bbb", "12:30:00", 0,2,1
]
| mv-expand kind = array monster = pack_dictionary("Monster1", monster1, "Monster2", monster2, "Monster3", monster3)
| extend Monster = tostring(monster[0]), Quantity = toint(monster[1])
| project-away monster*
```

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1VQy2rDMBC8G/wPQie7KKBHoWDorZcccij0FkxY26IoiWUhb9oY%20vFdJ4rdSmLZmVntqwOk25wtK7Zvh3CGycZqxOj8p2AfrrcjQh8qnL0AXrB%208CPaqCrncUH6HzIzKvNsn2dsPhwAuGBc6UpKeuQroYW5y%20KPrJL8LF6EfMhN0yTZJFnSb5VndZ79sP5rY6/UWcdOjswrgxhherRCOEB7OnSuRTd4iFPBd2kCvg5D6ROrV1avrFlZU85V7RUtVdstVXC4L61IYXtZl4K9X8Cjw%20kWQEtZVFXf0oQ4HG2LG/heW376BbMBxweTAQAA)

###### `pack_array()`x2 + `mv-expand`

```
datatable (ID_player:string, Timestamp:timespan, monster1:int, monster2:int, monster3:int)
[
     "aaa", "12:00:00", 1,2,3
    ,"aaa", "12:10:00", 4,7,0
    ,"bbb", "12:30:00", 0,2,1
]
| mv-expand     Monster  = pack_array("Monster1", "Monster2", "Monster3") to typeof(string)
               ,Quantity = pack_array( monster1,   monster2,   monster3 ) to typeof(int)
| project-away  monster*
```

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1VQTYvCMBC9F/ofhpzaZYSmWVgoePPiwYOwt2WRqWalatOQzn4E/PGb2ljrJIf38iaTl3cgDqu%20aMjWq529kNeu6tk15ojw3rS6Z2ptxQOyZBDazvSsnawawxMrn5gaWJ4mH2kCQwkiEghCllVRhB2wxBLVKONMllF%20xTcs7nJd11FWUS7CbZkmn2lyhfZnof%20Cs8Ptqc3oAGAJlvbnHTlHPhPxWA5zIi5nWIkcuAP2Vndf2fj7PJp/FG6/yXDD/nn4lAiGnnseM6xgPnxM5grWdSe95wX9kp9aX/4BEJlbRY4BAAA=)

###### `pack_array()` + `mv-expand with_itemindex`

```
datatable (ID_player:string, Timestamp:timespan, monster1:int, monster2:int, monster3:int)
[
     "aaa", "12:00:00", 1,2,3
    ,"aaa", "12:10:00", 4,7,0
    ,"bbb", "12:30:00", 0,2,1
]
| mv-expand with_itemindex = i Quantity = pack_array(monster1, monster2, monster3) to typeof(int)
| extend Monster = strcat("Monster", tostring(i + 1))  
| project ID_player, Timestamp, Monster, Quantity
```

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1VQTUvEMBC9F/ofhp5SjNC0glDwthcPHgRvImXajhp380E6agv7403px65JDvPyZh5vXo8cb3siEI%20Hxp9wolAPHLT9kPCiDQ2Mxtc8Vx6tBOPswBRUrS3vqPyHqhnlafKaJjCfDBEzCZkq66KIL9ZKlrJaaHlFq5W%20k/ey2Oi2bVe6WukiTqs0eUuTM5ifWxqjsx5%20NX82mslo29MID6Dh%20Rsta54i8NgdGwwBJ7GtcLF/sZ4DO%20DJk3sXyxZnoJEp6j8tLVEr5tMhi2z9iY7YLZkJDTeg8hxgHvTBfVHHsCd7Fanc9OTu8g/tY/E9jAEAAA==)

Comment: Thanks David! I like pack + dictionary because it tastes like python. Lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

you could use a combination of `pack()` & `mv-apply`.

for example:

```
datatable (ID_player:string, Timestamp:timespan, monster1:int, monster2:int, monster3:int)
[
     "aaa", "12:00:00", 1,2,3
    ,"aaa", "12:10:00", 4,7,0
    ,"bbb", "12:30:00", 0,2,1
]
| mv-apply c = pack("monster1", monster1, "monster2", monster2, "monster3", monster3) on (
    extend Monster = tostring(bag_keys(c)[0])
    | extend Quantity = tolong(c[Monster])
)
| project-away monster*, c
```

| ID_player | Timestamp | Monster | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 12:00:00 | monster1 | 1 |
| aaa | 12:00:00 | monster2 | 2 |
| aaa | 12:00:00 | monster3 | 3 |
| aaa | 12:10:00 | monster1 | 4 |
| aaa | 12:10:00 | monster2 | 7 |
| aaa | 12:10:00 | monster3 | 0 |
| bbb | 12:30:00 | monster1 | 0 |
| bbb | 12:30:00 | monster2 | 2 |
| bbb | 12:30:00 | monster3 | 1 |